# incompatibility of max_allowed_packet in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, dump

I have a client and I want to dump a row such as :

```
$ mysqldump -uroot -p pahlevan_azad mp_posts --where="id='655'"  --max-allowed-packet=1024 > dump.sql
Warning: option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 1024 adjusted to 4096
Enter password:
```

Because I have the following value in server :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
max_allowed_packet  1024
```

And I don't have any permission to change it.I only have a phpmyadmin.

What do you recommend?
How can I set max_allowed_packet such as server?

**Update:**
even I tested with 1K, But I got the above error.

Answer (score 1):

16777216 is a reasonable value; 1024 is not.  The error message is just a warning, saying that 1024 is below the minimum allowed value.

Try the mysqldump with 16777216.

Comment: How can i match with server?

Comment: I got `#1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes `

Comment: I think at least number is 4096 And server is old mysql server

Comment: I checked 97 machines; the smallest value I saw was 1M.  4K is too small.

Comment: Then my target machine has a old mysql.

Comment: What version?..

Comment: 5.1.73 on CentOS

Comment: What value did you have for `net_buffer_length`?